# FuzzyWuzzy's fuzz.ratio not behaving as expected

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I am using fuzzywuzzy to do fuzzy matching and expect fuzz.ratio to work the same/yield the same results when it's used independently vs. when it is used as the 'scorer' parameter in the process module. However, it does not.

I have tried testing all other scorers using them independently as well as in process.extract, and the give the same results.

```
fuzz.ratio('So','SO)
>> 50
```

When using it in process module where on of the comparisons is the following:

```
...process.extract('So',['SO'])
>> 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/process.py) and [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py), it seems that `process.extract()` forces everything to lower case, while running `fuzz.ratio()` directly does not.

If you use the flag `processor=None`, you get the expected results.

```
process.extract('So', ['SO'], processor=None, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
>> [('SO', 50)]
```